Needed Jolt Specification in NiFi Processor to Convert JSON
I am new to using Jolt specifications and need some assistance. I am trying to convert a JSON object using a Jolt specification in an Apache NiFi processor. The input JSON looks like this:
{
  "keys": [
    "CustomerNumber",
    "CustomerName",
    "IsActive"
  ],
  "values": [
    [
      "12345",
      "ABC Corp",
      "1"
    ],
    [
      "67890",
      "XYZ Ltd",
      "0"
    ]
  ]
}

I need to transform this into a key-value pair format, where each object in the values array is converted to a JSON object with the keys as field names. The desired output should look like this:
[
  {
    "CustomerNumber": "12345",
    "IsActive": "1",
    "CustomerName": "ABC Corp"
  },
  {
    "CustomerNumber": "67890",
    "IsActive": "0",
    "CustomerName": "XYZ Ltd"
  }
]

Could someone help me with the correct Jolt specification to achieve this transformation in NiFi? Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

You can add the following shift transformation into the specificaton part of a  JoltTtansformJSON proessor :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "values": {
        "*": {
          "*": "[&1].@(3,keys[&])" //need to traverse 3 layers in order to reach the level of "keys" array
                                   //use the index values of the urrent level by [&] for the innermost match
                                   //use the indexes of the "values" array through [&1]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Hi @Ryan , can you please upvote as well, since only it increments the score for the tag badge, thanx in advance.
